# DRY usage of Common directive used across all views

Tags: angularjs

If I have an angular router of say 10 views, and each view has the same banner is it redundant to have to declare the same directive that wraps the banner and its controller in each view?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Try posting examples of what you have, and why you think it's redundant/not redundant to structure your code that way.

Comment: It's somewhat redundant, if you want to use it across your app just put it in your shell page, the page with the `ng-view` in it.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand yeah I agree, thats the best way for my use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases - yes, it's redundant.

You just need to create some Angular module and create directive inside this module:

```
angular.module('angularApplication', [])
       .directive('directiveName', function directiveDefinition() {....});
```

Then you use "ng-app" attribute for root element of your Angular application + use this directive:

```
<html ng-app="angularApplication">
    <directiveName></directiveName>
...
</html>
```

In some rare cases you will need to create multiple directives - but these cases are quite rare (and could be achieved by one directive with different directive attributes).